# Elixir UUID. How to handle 500 error when UUID doesn't match

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, uuid

```
def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
  with {:ok, user} <- UserAction.get_user(id)
    |> put_status(200)
    |> render("show.json", %{user: user})
  else
    {:error, :not_found} -> {:error, :not_found, %User{id: id}}
  end
end
```

When id is invalid, `Ecto` raises:

```
Ecto.Query.CastError - cannot be dumped to type :binary_id in query.
```

My `get_user` function:

```
query = from(u in User, where u.id == ^id)

case Repo.all(query) do
  [%User{} = user] -> {:ok, user}
  _ -> {:error, :not_found}
end
```

Is there any convenient way for handling this error to prevent 500 responses?

Comment: You can use `Ecto.UUID.dump/1` to check the id. https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.UUID.html#dump/1

Comment: Can you post the code for your `get_user` function?

Comment: @Sheharyar see question, added it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've ended up with guard macros

```
defmacro is_uuid(value) do
  quote do
    is_binary(unquote(value)) and byte_size(unquote(value)) == 36 and
      binary_part(unquote(value), 8, 1) == "-" and binary_part(unquote(value), 13, 1) == "-" and
      binary_part(unquote(value), 18, 1) == "-" and binary_part(unquote(value), 23, 1) == "-"
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
def get_user(id) when is_uuid(id) do
  Repo.get(User, id)
end

def get_user(_id), do: {:error, :not_found}
```

Answer (score 6):

That's a known issue with `UUID`, `Binary` and other [ecto](/questions/tagged/ecto) types that need to conform to a specific standard (*It's a feature, not a bug™️*). Like *@TheAnh* mentioned, you can use `Ecto.UUID.dump/1` to check if the `id` is valid, but I prefer straight-up rescuing it:

```ex
def get_user(id) do
  Repo.get(User, id)
rescue
  Ecto.Query.CastError -> nil
end
```

---

### Override `Repo`

The above example can get tedious because you'll have to `rescue` everywhere you call `get`. So I override the `get/3` function in `MyApp.Repo`:

```ex
# lib/my_app/repo.ex
defoverridable [get: 2, get: 3]
def get(query, id, opts \\ []) do
  super(query, id, opts)
rescue
  Ecto.Query.CastError -> nil
end
```

---

### Use `fetch` for Tuple format

You should use `fetch_*` method names instead of `get_*` to return values in `tuple` format (to avoid confusion with default `Repo` methods):

```ex
# lib/my_app/repo.ex
def fetch(query, id, opts \\ []) do
  case get(query, id, opts) do
    nil -> {:error, :not_found}
    schema -> {:ok, schema}
  end
end
```

And call it like this in your main function:

```ex
def fetch_user(id) do
  Repo.fetch(User, id)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To return 400 you need to update the `conn` with the appropriate status and then render.

```
conn
|> put_status(:not_found)
|> put_view(YourApp.ErrorView)
|> render("404.html")
```

This would be carried out in the else clause of your `with` expression. You can take this idea further with custom errors: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/errors.html

I would advise to check if the input is invalid before operating on it if possible.
 There are a few ways you. could validate prior to trying to execute a db query. One solid way is try and cast the value before attempting the query.

```
iex(1)> Ecto.UUID.cast("no good")
:error
iex(2)> Ecto.UUID.cast("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx")
:error
iex(3)> Ecto.UUID.cast("de851708-7f7a-40e1-b8ec-da2baec30839")
{:ok, "de851708-7f7a-40e1-b8ec-da2baec30839"}
```

Given the above behavior above you can wrap your `with` expression in a case expression. Though, I'm not sure I would use `with` here either, it's better for pipelines.

```
case Ecto.UUID.cast(id) do
  :error ->
    conn |> put_status(400) |> render("error.json", %{message: "Some Message"})

  {:ok, uuid} ->
    case UserAction.get_user(uuid) do
      {:ok, user} ->
        conn |> put_status(200) |> render("show.json", %{user: user})

      _ ->
        conn |> put_status(404) |> render("error.json", %{message: "User not found"})
    end
end
```

Comment: Edited a bit question, i need something like 
`defimpl Plug.Exception, for: Ecto.Query.CastError do
  def status(_exception), do: 404
end`
but it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @vlad-horbachevsky answer, I extended it to my version of guard function:

````
  defguard is_uuid(value)
           when is_binary(value) and byte_size(value) == 36 and
                  binary_part(value, 1, 1) in ~w|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F| and
                  binary_part(value, 2, 1) in ~w|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F| and
                  binary_part(value, 3, 1) in ~w|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F| and
                  binary_part(value, 4, 1) in ~w|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F| and
                  binary_part(value, 5, 1) in ~w|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F| and
                  binary_part(value, 6, 1) in ~w|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F| and
                  binary_part(value, 7, 1) in ~w|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F| and
                  binary_part(value, 8, 1) == "-" and
                  binary_part(value, 9, 1) in ~w|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F| and
                  binary_part(value, 10, 1) in ~w|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F| and
                  binary_part(value, 11, 1) in ~w|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F| and
                  binary_part(value, 12, 1) in ~w|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F| and
                  binary_part(value, 13, 1) == "-" and
                  binary_part(value, 14, 1) in ~w|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F| and
                  binary_part(value, 15, 1) in ~w|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F| and
                  binary_part(value, 16, 1) in ~w|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F| and
                  binary_part(value, 17, 1) in ~w|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F| and
                  binary_part(value, 18, 1) == "-" and
                  binary_part(value, 19, 1) in ~w|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F| and
                  binary_part(value, 20, 1) in ~w|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F| and
                  binary_part(value, 21, 1) in ~w|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F| and
                  binary_part(value, 22, 1) in ~w|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F| and
                  binary_part(value, 23, 1) == "-" and
                  binary_part(value, 24, 1) in ~w|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F| and
                  binary_part(value, 25, 1) in ~w|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F| and
                  binary_part(value, 26, 1) in ~w|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F| and
                  binary_part(value, 27, 1) in ~w|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F| and
                  binary_part(value, 28, 1) in ~w|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F| and
                  binary_part(value, 29, 1) in ~w|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F| and
                  binary_part(value, 30, 1) in ~w|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F| and
                  binary_part(value, 31, 1) in ~w|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F| and
                  binary_part(value, 32, 1) in ~w|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F| and
                  binary_part(value, 33, 1) in ~w|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F| and
                  binary_part(value, 34, 1) in ~w|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F| and
                  binary_part(value, 35, 1) in ~w|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F|
    ```
````